# Why does Class.isLocalClass always Boolean.FALSE?

Tags: java, class, reflection, stereotype

I've got a simple Method that returns me always "-undefined-".

```
public static String getStereoType(Class<?> clazz) {
    String result = "-undefined-";
    if (clazz.isEnum()) {
        result = "enum";
    } else if (clazz.isInterface()) {
        result = "interface";
    } else if (clazz.isLocalClass() || clazz.isMemberClass()) {
        result = "class";
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I call this Method with Object.class or Long.class always is the result "-undefined-".

```
 List<Class<?>> superClazzes = ClassUtil.getSuperClazzList(clazz);
    for (Class<?> c: superClazzess){
        String stereoType = ClassUtil.getStereoType(c.getClass());
        }

public static List<Class<?>> getSuperClazzList(Class<?> clazz) {
        List<Class<?>> resultList = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        Class<?> superClass = clazz.getSuperclass();
        if (superClass != null) {
            resultList.add(superClass);
            resultList.addAll(getSuperClazzList(superClass));
        }
        return resultList;
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html and http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_10.htm.

Comment: What do you expect it to retutn? For which input?

Comment: Can you post example of how you use this method? It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: What results you expected for `Object.class` or `Long.class` and why do you think your method should give you such results?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to get? So what are the possible stereo types you need? What I know of is:

- Enum
- Interface
- Primitive (e.g. double, but **not** Double)
- Class (everything else!)

And from the class API I can find that you might also differ between:

- annotation (actual an interface in java)
- synthetic (I'm not sure what this is)
- local (defined inside a method)

But they might not be interesting for ULM diagrams at all.

Implementation of `toString()` from the JVM `Class` is:

```
public String toString() {
    return (isInterface() ? "interface " : (isPrimitive() ? "" : "class ")) + getName();
}
```

This might give you some hint as well.

Hope it helps.

Edit: This should do the job:

```
public static String getStereoType(Class<?> clazz) {
        String result = "class";
        if (clazz.isEnum()) {
            result = "enum";
        } else if (clazz.isInterface()) {
            result = "interface";
        } 
        else if (clazz.isPrimitive()) {
            result = "primitive";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Sure thats what i have found but i need only if it is a a interface or a class and so on, i dont want to split the string to delete the name. (I think this is to dirty.)

Comment: The point is, you should first find out what types of stereotypes you need to distinguish and than you can find out who to detect which. Rather than just going through all properties the JVM offers.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your title, `isLocalClass()` does not *always* return `false`: it returns `true` for types declared within a method.  Similarly, `isMemberClass()` returns `true` for types declared within another type.

Consider:

```
public class Outer {

    interface MemberClass {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class LocalClass {}

        System.out.printf(
            "%s/%s%n",
            LocalClass.class.isLocalClass(),
            LocalClass.class.isMemberClass()
        );

        System.out.printf(
            "%s/%s%n",
            MemberClass.class.isLocalClass(),
            MemberClass.class.isMemberClass()
        );
    }
}
```

This code, when executed, prints out `true/false` followed by `false/true`.  Together, they *only account for types which are defined within another class, or within a method*.  Neither strictly depends on the target type being a `class` as opposed to an `interface` or `enum`, so you cannot use it to filter that way.

See @Tarion's excellent answer for the approach you *should* be taking (and accept his answer, as it more completely solves your problem).